# How do I host offline LAN mode Danger Zone or at least use DZ maps in DM mode?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I tried to use

```
game_type 6; game_mode 0; map dz_blacksite;
```

or

```
game_type 6; game_mode 0; changelevel dz_blacksite
```

and

```
game_type 6; game_mode 0; changelevel dz_blacksite; sv_dz_team_count 2; sv_dz_jointeam_allowed 1; sv_dz_autojointeam 0; sv_dz_player_spawn_armor 1
```

but the game ended right after the map loaded

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/1743353798885446785/)